# Construct a binary tree such that the Post-order traversal should give the sorted result

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search

I know that In-order traversal(VISIT LEFT, VISIT ROOT, VISIT RIGHT) on a binary search tree gives me a sorted result. But I need to do a Post-order traversal (VISIT LEFT, VISIT RIGHT, VISIT ROOT) on a binary tree and the result should give me sorted values.

In order to achieve that, how should I construct my binary tree?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the root is visited last, it must contain the largest item. Since the left subtree is visited before the right subtree, all items in the left subtree must be smaller than any item in the right subtree.

So to construct a tree like this you can proceed as follows: If you insert an item which is greater than the root, that item becomes the new root. If you insert an item which is smaller than the root but greater than the root of the left subtree, insert it into the right subtree. Else insert it into the left subtree.

Comment: This'll work, but it won't necessarily lead to a balanced tree - some sort of balancing algorithm is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the following at each node of the tree:

- Value at the node should be greater
  than all the values in the
  left-subtree and right-subtree.
- Values in the left sub-tree should be
  less than values in the right
  subtree.

Answer (score 1):

This subroutine is for the insertion in the tree
where tree structure is

```
struct tree

{

int data;
tree * left;
tree *right;

tree(int n)  // constructor 

{
       data = n;
       left = right = NULL;
    }
};
```

The algorithm is:
1. If tree is empty insert new node.
2. If data of new node is greater than data of root node make the new node
   root of tree.
3. else insert new node in the left subtree of tree.

```
tree * insert(tree *root,int n)

{

if(root == NULL)
{

    root = new tree(n);

    return root;
}
else
{

    if(n > root -> data)
    {
        tree * t = new tree(n);

        t -> left = root;

        return t;
    }

    else


    {

        root -> left = insert(root -> left,n);

        return root;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2216918/58668) gives a good on-line algorithm.  A somewhat simpler solution---which is not on-line and therefor possibly cheating---is to store a sorted linked list in the parent pointers.

In other words: sort the data; put the largest item in the root, make one of its subtrees empty and recursively construct a post-order-sorted tree of the remaining n-1 items into the other subtree.

The tree will have height n, the single leaf is the head of the list and the root is the tail-most element.  If you walk through the tree from leaf to root the elements will form an increasing sequence, and this path will correspond exactly to a postorder traversal.

Answer (score -1):

Deletion

- if leaf, then delete regularly
- if it has only one son connect son to father
- else, delete the root,replace it with its right son,then connect left sub-tree to leftmost vertex in right sub-tree.

for example:

```
    7                                                            6
   / \                                                          / \
  3   6             =========DELETING 7 ============>          4   5
 / \ / \                                                      /    
1  2 4  5                                                    3
                                                            / \
                                                           1   2
```